# SqlCommand parameter replace

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I tried to `Replace` sign "," with "." on `UPDATE` parameter but I'm not able to solve it. This parameter updates numeric type from `textBoxes` in`SQL DB`.

I thought that it can me done something like this, but `parameter` does not contain definiton `Replace`. is there any way to do that?

```
 prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poc_kli", poc_kli.Text).Replace(',', '.');
```

Comment: you have to do it on textbox prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poc_kli", poc_kli.Text.Replace(',', '.'));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the value first; then use **typed** data in the parameter. For example:

```
decimal val = decimal.Parse(poc_kli.Text);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("poc_kli", val);
```

Rather than "replace", you should use an appropriate `CultureInfo` (if it differs from the default culture) when parsing the value. For simplicity I'm assuming that you *do not* in fact need to specify a culture, but that this was simply an attempt at making SQL Server happy. But for example:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
// ^^^ or GetCulture, CurrentCulture, etc
decimal val = decimal.Parse(poc_kli.Text, culture);
```

Even better would be to completely separate your data access code from your UI code:

```
decimal val = decimal.Parse(poc_kli.Text);
SomeDatabaseMethod(val, ...other args);

...

public void SomeDatabaseMethod(decimal pocKli, ... other parameters ...)
{
    ...
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("poc_kli", pocKli);
    ...
}
```

The fact that you have one line of code that touches both the UI and the database (which are completely unrelated, or should be) should concern you.

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing at the wrong place in your code. Try:

```
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poc_kli", poc_kli.Text.Replace(',', '.'));
```

Comment: I would wager that the `,` vs `.` is an attempt to format it to make SQL Server happy with culture differences; as such, it is almost certainly entirely the wrong thing to do

Comment: I agree; I've already upvoted your comment as it's more useful as a general teaching point than mine (which only addresses the immediate technical issue).